# Is there a way to use this command without having to type 'y' all the time?

Tags: command-line, gem

I am trying to remove all ruby gems before uninstalling ruby.

The command I am using is: `sudo gem uninstall --all` to achieve this.

However, I have to type y continually to remove things.

Is there a way I could achieve the same thing without having to type `y` to remove all of the dependencies?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `yes`:

```
yes | sudo gem uninstall --all
```

Comment: For Mac users: 'gem uninstall -aIx' (that's a capital 'eye')

Answer (score 6):

Just using `-x` option:

```
sudo gem uninstall -a -x
```

Comment: wrong. if you're trying to uninstall a gem which will, eg, lead to an unmet dependency, you'll still have a prompt.

Comment: (`-x` tells only to remove the executables)

Comment: I'll do this instead: `\`gem list aws\`.each_line { |x| p system("gem uninstall #{x.spli
t[0]} --all -x -I") }` - this removes hundreds of annoying AWS gems I have that depends of one another...